# why would these two SQL statements resulted an operational deadlock error?

Tags: python, mysql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `notify` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `notify_type` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `notify_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `create_time` timestamp NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `update_time` timestamp NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `notify_id` (`notify_id`,`notify_type`,`user`),
  KEY `Index_time` (`create_time`),
  KEY `user_update` (`user`,`update_time`)
)
```

and two SQL queries executed consecutively and then committed together

```
if user_id:
    insert into notify (notify_type,notify_id,user,create_time) 
    values (%s,%s,%s,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE update_time=update_time, (type, id, user_id)

    update notify set update_time=NOW() where notify_type = %s 
    and notify_id =%s and user!=%s,(type, id, user_id)
else:
    update reply_notify set update_time=NOW() where notify_type = %s 
    and notify_id =%s, (type, id)
commit()
```

it often resulted in

> OperationalError: (1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction')

Would anyone could help me figure out why it is? I've consulted the MySQL document, I doubt there is some thing related to the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause, but I still can't figure it out.

Could it be some code execute to the if branch, while other code execute to the else branch, and then those two transaction deadlocked?

Comment: yes. I've posted under the table

Comment: Note that your `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause does nothing since you assign update_time to the existing value in the update_time column. That aside, why are you trying to send two queries that update the same row in one transaction?

Comment: doesn't that two sql do exactly the same thing? beside, `update` `set` lock the table if you are under myisam, hence prevent the insert running. try put a commit right above the update, or change the query order to let update finish it's write first

Comment: the second one is used to update the records where user != user_id, so I think it is different from the first one, right?

Comment: Which database engine are you using for the table? Different engines have different locking behaviours.

Comment: this table is set as ENGINE=InnoDB

Answer (score 1):

According to [MySQL's doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locks-set.html), your query looks fine. However there is [a bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52020) that may be related.

You can try switching the engine used by the table, in 5.0 you can try [BDB (Berkeley DB)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bdb-storage-engine.html) but it is unsupported now, otherwise I afraid the best bet is MyISAM.

Or, putting [`LOCK TABLES ... UNLOCK TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/lock-tables.html) around the insert may solve the problem.
Failing that, you can try to put lock tables around the whole block (including the updates) to see whether it is really this part that is giving you trouble.

Keep in mind that table lock is usually not good for performance, and MyISAM is not designed for frequent update, but you may not have much choice.

---

```
lock tables notify write;
insert into notify (notify_type,notify_id,user,create_time) 
values (%s,%s,%s,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE update_time=update_time, (type, id, user_id);
unlock tables;
```